# Inline CSS works perfectly fine. CSS File class works partially

Tags: css

I've stumbled upon a weird problem. I'm designing a table with CSS. When I give the `<td>` elements a class with a background gradient and some basic text styling, the gradient works perfectly fine, but the text styling is completely ignored.

When I remove the text styling from the CSS class and add it to inline CSS with `style=""`, it works perfectly fine! Now I'm not a designer so I probebly just miss something somewhere, but this just seems very odd to me.

Relevant CSS:

```
.top_td {
    background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #001e5b 5%, #00153e 100%);
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #001e5b), color-stop(1, #00153e) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #001e5b 5%, #00153e 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#001e5b", endColorstr="#00153e");
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#001e5b,333333);background-color:#00153e;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="top_td" style="">
        <strong>WELKOM</strong>
    </td>
    <td class="top_td">
        <strong>OPENINGSTIJDEN</strong>
    </td>
    <td class="top_td">
        <strong>ADRES</strong>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="top_td" style="text-align:center;font-size:14px;font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;">
        <strong>INLINE CSS</strong>
    </td>
    <td class="top_td" style="text-align:center;font-size:14px;font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;">
        <strong>WORKS</strong>
    </td>
    <td class="top_td" style="text-align:center;font-size:14px;font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;">
        <strong>PERFECTLY FINE</strong>
    </td>
</tr>
```

To view the result yourself, check code snippet:

```css
.TableDIV {
 margin:0px;padding:0px;
 width:100%;
 
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
 
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
 
 -moz-border-radius-topright:5px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
 border-top-right-radius:5px;
 
 -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
 border-top-left-radius:5px;
}
.TableDIV table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0px;padding:0px;
}
#top_table tr:last-child td:last-child {
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}
#top_table tr:first-child td:first-child {
 -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
 border-top-left-radius:5px;
}
#top_table tr:first-child td:last-child {
 -moz-border-radius-topright:5px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
 border-top-right-radius:5px;
}
#top_table tr:last-child td:first-child{
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
}
.TableDIV td{
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align:left;
 padding:0;margin:0;
 font-size:10px;
 font-family:Verdana;
 font-weight:normal;
 color:#000000;
}
.top_td {
 background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #001e5b 5%, #00153e 100%);
 background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #001e5b), color-stop(1, #00153e) );
 background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #001e5b 5%, #00153e 100% );
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#001e5b", endColorstr="#00153e");
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#001e5b,333333);background-color:#00153e;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:14px;
 font-family:Verdana;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="TableDIV">
 <table id="top_table">
  <tr>
   <td class="top_td" style="">
    <strong>IN CSS</strong>
   </td>
   <td class="top_td">
    <strong>FILE</strong>
   </td>
   <td class="top_td">
    <strong>DOESN'T WORK</strong>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="background: #777777;text-align:center;">
    <img src="http://www.petervanderleegte.nl/images/IMG_6317.JPG" style="margin:0; padding:0; width: 130px;">
   </td>
   <td style="vertical-align: top;background: #777777;">
    <table style="border-left: 1px solid #333; border-right: 1px solid #333;">
     <tbody>
      <tr style="background-color: #989898;">
       <td>Maandag:</td>
       <td style="font-style: italic;">08:00 - 17:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Dinsdag:</td>
       <td style="font-style: italic;">08:00 - 17:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background-color: #989898;">
       <td>Woensdag:</td>
       <td style="font-style: italic;">08:00 - 17:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Donderdag:</td>
       <td style="font-style: italic;">08:00 - 17:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background-color: #989898;">
       <td>Vrijdag:</td>
       <td style="font-style: italic;">08:00 - 17:00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Zaterdag:</td>
       <td style="font-style: italic;">Op afspraak</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background-color: #989898;">
       <td>Zondag:</td>
       <td style="font-style: italic;">Gesloten</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td style="vertical-align: top;background: #777777;">
    Dummy data <br />
    TODO: Address info
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="top_td" style="text-align:center;font-size:14px;font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;">
    <strong>INLINE CSS</strong>
   </td>
   <td class="top_td" style="text-align:center;font-size:14px;font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;">
    <strong>WORKS</strong>
   </td>
   <td class="top_td" style="text-align:center;font-size:14px;font-family:Verdana;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;">
    <strong>PERFECTLY FINE</strong>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a concept called selector specificity, which means that styles will be applied depending on how specific the selectors are. If you have multiple style declarations that apply to the same element, the most specific one will be applied. For example, the `.top_td` style will be applied but the declarations that are defined in `.TableDIV td` will override the the ones in `.top_td` because the selector is more specific.

The selectors go (from least specific to most specific):

1. Tags and pseudo-elements (:before, :after, etc.)
2. Classes, attributes, pseudo-classes (e.g. :hover)
3. IDs

See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

In your case if you absolutely want your .top_td styles to work anytime, you could set the selector to something like `.TableDIV #top_table td.top_td`, for example.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! That explains why it didn't work as I expected!

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
.TableDIV td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000000;
}
```

is overriding your .top_td.
You can set !important to each style
like

```
.top_td {
    background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #001e5b 5%, #00153e 100%) !important;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #001e5b), color-stop(1, #00153e) ) !important;
```

Comment: That indeed solved the problem! Still I think it's a bit odd because I always thought that CSS worked from top to bottom. Meaning my `top_td` class should've overwritten the `TableDIV td`? Could be me though. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: here is a good reference about css: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-priority-level/       - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

If two selectors apply to the same element, the one with higher specificity wins.

`.TableDIV td`  selector override `.top_td` selector

U can refer : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/